Mean squared error of an estimator of samples that are uniformly distributed in (-a,a)
Let $MSE(\hat{\theta}) := \mathbb{E}((\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2)$ be the mean squared error of a statistic $\hat{\theta}$.
My question is at the end of the post. The rest is my workout.

Let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be an i.i.d. sample from the uniform distribution on $(-a,a)$.
(a) Find the method of moments estimator $\hat{a_{1}}$. Is it unbiased?
(b) Find the MLE $\hat{a}_{2}$.Is it unbiased?
(c) Which estimator among the above two has a lower MSE?

(a) Method of moments: The first moment vanishes, so by equating the second moment, we obtain $$\hat{a}_1 = \sqrt{\dfrac{3(X_1^2+X_2^2+\ldots+X_n^2)}{n}}.$$
But by Jensen's inequality $$\mathbb{E}(\hat{a}_1) < \sqrt{E(\hat{a}_1^2)} = a$$ and thus the estimator is biased.
(b) A routine calculation shows $$\hat{a}_{2} = max\{|X_1|,|X_2|,\ldots,|X_n|\}.$$ Further $|X|$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,a)$, so using order statistic distribution formulae, we get $\mathbb{E}(\hat{a}_2) = \dfrac{na}{n+1}$.
(c) I can compute the MSE of the MLE estimate since the distribution is easy to compute. So the actual question is

How do we compute the MSE of $\hat{a}_1$?


Notice that you don't have to compute any MSE: you just have to determine which is larger.

How do we find which of the two has larger MSE?

Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you
is grounds for closing.
